# Diophantine equations with arithmetical functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

I want to know is the diophantine equations that contain arithmetic functions are an interesting topic to research? (For example $\varphi(x)=cx-1$ and $\varphi(x)=\sigma(x)-1$.)

$\sigma(x)$ is the sum of divisors of $x$.

Comment: These are not typically called Diophantine equations, which generally refer to systems of pol\iynomial equations. But equations of the sort you're asking abouot are often studied. For example, the equation $\sigma(n)=2n$ characterizes perfect numbers. And there are also equations involving the Euler $\phi$ function that have been much studied.

Comment: Is this topic not good as topic of research ?

Comment: your examples, especially the second one, look strange

Comment: $\sigma(x)$ is the sum of divisors of $x$.

Comment: This seems to be quite close to your other question: [Diophantine equations or associative operations on ordered lattice](https://mathoverflow.net/q/422720).

Comment: Yes, I have tried to explain more about it there.

Comment: $\sigma(x)-\phi(x)\ge(x+1)-(x-1)=2$ for $x\ge2$.

Comment: Here are some questions discussed in Guy, Unsolved Problems In Number Theory, 3rd edition. B11, solutions of $m\sigma(m)=n\sigma(n)$. $\sigma(a)/a=\sigma(b)/b$. $\sigma(n)=({\rm rad\ } n)^2$, where rad is the radical of $n$. B12, analogues with $d(n)$, $\sigma_k(n)$. B13, solutions of $\sigma(n)=\sigma(n+1)$ (and variations). B15, solutions of $\sigma(q)+\sigma(r)=\sigma(q+r)$. B18, solutions of $d(n)=d(n+1)$. B36 is devoted to $\phi(n)$. B37, does $\phi(n)$ divide $n-1$ for some composite $n$? B38, solutions of $\phi(m)=\sigma(n)$. B41, iterations of $\phi$ and $\sigma$. (continued)

Comment: B42, behavior of $\phi(\sigma(n))$ and $\sigma(\phi(n))$. And more.

Comment: Thank you so much. But why do they need to solve these type of equations?

Comment: Because they are there.

Answer (score 2):

This is in response to your question as to whether this is an "interesting or good topic of research." There is no answer to such a question. If you find it interesting, that makes it interesting. If you want to know whether others find it interesting, you can look for (recent) research on such questions. There's a fair amount. I've listed a number of articles below. If you're asking whether this is a major area of current research in number theory, I'd say probably not; but again, to each their own.

Here are some MathStackExchange questions and answers dealing with equations that involve arithmetic functions:

- [Find all $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $\sigma(n) + \phi(n) = n\tau(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2528250)
- [Show that the only solution to $\phi(n) =n-2$ is $n=4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393437/)

And here are some articles:

- [Diophantine equations involving Euler's totient function, Yong-Gao Chen, Hao Tian (2017)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00180)
- [Equations involving arithmetic functions, Gabriel Mincu and
  Laurenƫiu Panaitopol, Carpathian Journal of Mathematics. Vol. 22, No.
  1/2 (2006), pp. 91-98 (8 pages)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43998912?seq=1)
- [Luca, Florian, Equations involving arithmetic functions of Fibonacci and Lucas numbers. Fibonacci Quart. 38 (2000), no. 1, 49–55](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.376.651)